# How to disable mnemonic shortcuts in 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice, gtk, gtk3

As far as I understand this is  not distribution based issue, but something that happens with newer GTK versions, and thus all newer Ubuntu releases after 20.04.
So whenever I have a toolbar in an app (LibreOffice, Terminal etc.) ALT + F for example selects the Files tab. Like so:[image: Like so]

This however overrides any application specific shortcuts like CTRL + ALT + F (insert footnote). I don't use these mnemonic shortcuts so I would be better off with them just disabled. So how should I achieve that? Ubuntu shortcut options did not have these listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mnemonics are *not* defined at the level of the desktop. They are defined at the level of the application. These, therefore, would need to be disable per application. In a majority of cases, this is not user configurable, and would need to be changed in the source code.

So for for your *problem Y*, i.e., how to disable the menu hotkeys.

In as far of your *real problem X*, i.e., where your custom shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to insert a footnote does not work and instead behaves as if you pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, this is a [bug reported](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146174) for the 7.3.1.3 release. As you did not specify the version of Ubuntu you use, nor the version, it can be assumed that you run an affected version. The issue was resolved in the 7.3.3 build.

Comment: Yes I have mapped CTRL + ALT + F to add footnote myself. However whenever I do this files gets opened because mnemonics shortcut takes priority for some reason. The only other option would be disabling the toolbar altogether, then my LibreOffice shortcuts are working. However I want to have a toolbar. I would understand this happening if the shortcuts are identical but mnemonics will override all shortcuts which uses the Alt key.

Comment: Please add your Ubuntu version to your question. I cannot reproduce this. Not sure also how you expect the visibility of toolbars to interfer with this.

Comment: 22.04 for example. I find this issue with most of the mid term releases between 20.04 and the current LTS.

Comment: You may have missed the update to my answer: you are facing a bug in Libreoffice, which is solved in 7.3.3

Comment: Just saw it. That clarified things a lot. I previously tried asking this in LO community but they directed me to OS side of things. Normal deb. package is still an older version but I can manage with the flatpak version at this point. Thanks!